# What is correct- 'starts from' or 'starts at' when we talk about the cost of something?

Tags: punctuation

I know Grammarly is not a much reliable source for all things grammar. So when I see the mistake of punctuation in the marketing copy, I decided to ask about the same here.

Here is a sentence:

> During this festive season, our app development cost starts ***from*** just $10000.

Here, Grammarly shows 'at' instead of 'from'. Is it correct? I am perplexed because I have an impression that when we talk about the price range, it is correct to use 'from'.

What's your take on this?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is correct to use "from" when talking about a price range. However, your sentence does not refer to a price range but rather the *starting point* of a price range. As such, it is correct to say that the *start* occurs *at* $10000. However, "from" in this case is certainly understood and in use.

"From" could be used without the explicit reference to the starting point in order to convey the same meaning.

> During this festive season, we offer app development costs from just $10000.